# multiple search by jquery getting strucked if he removes any of the checkbox

Tags: jquery, search, checkbox, filter

Hi am working on coupons site here i got a challenge where if someone search for particular city deals i can get but at the same time even i fhe search for search by city with of particular multiple store its getting tough to handle ,, and even if he uncheck the checkbox the previous data should be

```
if((($(".city").is(':checked') == true) && ($(".store").is(':checked') == true)) && ($(".category").is(':checked') == true)) ){
       alert('hi');
       $('.citystore').change(function() {
        var cdd=$(this).val();
    if((($(".td1").is(':checked') == true) && ($(".td").is(':checked') == true)) || (($(".td").is(':checked') == true) && ($(".td1").is(':checked') == true))){
    $list=$("#itemslist");
    var kk=$('#city input:checkbox:checked').val();
    var kkk=$('#store input:checkbox:checked').val();
    var checked=[]
       var city=$('#city input:checkbox:checked').map(function(i,e){
       checked.push(e.value);
       }).get();


       var store=$('#store input:checkbox:checked').map(function(){
       return this.id;
       }).get();

    $.each(checked, function(index, item) {
        var co=item;
    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url : '/localdeals/test11.php',
      data :
      {
      store:kkk,
      city:co
      },
      dataType : "html",
      success : function(data){
      if(data){
    $('#itemslist').remove();
           $('#con1').find('li[data-value="' +co+'"]').remove(function(){
        $(this).remove();
       });
           $('#con1').append("<li data-value='" +co+ "'><div class='cho'>" + data +"</div></li>");
      }
      }
       });
       });
    }else {
        $('#con1').find('li[data-value="' +cdd+'"]').remove(function(){
        $(this).remove();
      });
    }
       });
       }
```

Comment: I you have to explain it a little better. What do you mean by "tough to handle"? And by "the previous data should be"? Try putting it in jsfiddle.

Comment: HI actually i am working on dynamic content where each and every checkbox is with of same class name, if some one clicks on any of the  checkbox , ajax url is firing for all input check-boxes and it is time taking